# Tesseract OCR mftraining Error code 2001 with 2 fonts in the font_properties file

Tags: tesseract

I am trying create new language data for `Japanese` with 2 fonts.

```
1. Arial Unicode MS
2. MS ゴシック　(MS Gothic)
```

I am not sure how to create `font_properties file` with `command line` for two `fonts`.

Usually I run `> echo Arial_Unicode_MS 0 0 1 0 0 >font_properties --` to create `font` properties file with one `font`.
Since, I am going to use two `fonts` I edited the `file` to add the second `font`.

But, when I execute `mftraining` , for the first `font` whether it is `Arial Unicode MS` or `MS ゴシック` it just works fine. But I get `"malloc allocation error 2001` iff I reference the second font in the file.
I even used `Serak` trainer to `create font_properties` file.

I want to do, as shown below.

```
1. mftraining.exe -F font_properties -U unicharset -O lang.unicharset lang.font1.exp0.tr

2.mftraining.exe -F font_properties -U unicharset -O lang.unicharset lang.font2.exp0.tr

#1 throws no error if font1 is the first font in the file. But getting error with #2

#2 throws no error if font2 is the first font in the file. But getting error with #1
```

What is wrong with my steps?

Regards,
Sharon

Answer (score 0):

Your TIFF/Box files should have "Arial_Unicode_MS" in their names, not "font1" or "font2".